# Diagnosing error on Azure's Rock Paper Scissors sample Code

Tags: azure, web-hosting, azure-appservice

I am presently working through the [Azure Rock Paper Scissors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/rock-paper-scissors-customvision/rock-paper-scissors-customvision/) sample code found on Microsoft's website.I have built the application through Azure, and I have tested and published the Custom Vision resource. My Azure resources group looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY5UJ.png).

When I run the application it opens, counts to three, takes a picture, and then stops functioning. The screen just sits there and when I go to Azure's Log Stream I get the following error:

(node:23732) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Listening on \.\pipe\51f320fe-45d4-4c1b-8d7b-2dde79f0a294
ApplicationInsights:TelemetryClient [
'The URL object is failed to create.',TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URLat new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)at onParseError (node:internal/url:552:9)at new URL (node:internal/url:628:5)at NodeClient.TelemetryClient.trackDependency (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\293739~1.3\nodejs\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\Library\TelemetryClient.js:108:36)at ClientRequest. (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\293739~1.3\nodejs\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\HttpDependencies.js:224:24)at ClientRequest.clsBind (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\293739~1.3\nodejs\node_modules\cls-hooked\context.js:172:17)at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)at ClientRequest.emitted (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\293739~1.3\nodejs\node_modules\emitter-listener\listener.js:134:21)at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28) {input: 'https://<PUT_HOST_SERVER_HERE>:443',code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'}]

Does anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: The sever saide logic contains this:                                                                                    
const customVisionPostOptions = {
        hostname: PredictionConfig.ServerHost,
        port: 443,
        path: PredictionConfig.ModelPath,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Prediction-key': PredictionConfig.Key
        }             
    };

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by looking at and correcting the config.json.

Comment: To be an answer, this really needs more details. What was wrong with the `config.json`? What did you fix?

Comment: I fixed it, it had to be given the key for Custom Vision.